# Mainframe transaction files SFTP To Azure File Storage or Blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, mainframe, azcopy, azure-storage-files

Is there way to SFTP Mainframe files To Azure File Storage or Blob ?
Is there any other way of doing apart from AzCopy ?

This is for copying Transaction files from Mainframe to Azure Blob/File.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of [z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0) ship with sftp.  Dovetailed Technologies has their own implementation, which some shops use.

Whether or not you are allowed to exfiltrate potentially sensitive data is a local decision.

Further information of a more generic nature which may or may not be helpful is [here](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/rants/blob/master/advice-reading-mainframe-data.md).

Answer (score 0):

Blob storage now supports the SSH File Transfer Protocol (sFTP). Follow the detail article at below mentioned location about how to setup certificates on Mainframe and how to enable sFTP on Azure blob storage for direct Mainframe to Azure blob storage file transfer using sFTP.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/modernization-best-practices-and/mainframe-files-transfer-to-azure-data-platform-using-sftp/ba-p/3302194